# Filter users in views with a mandatory role and another role that is optional

Tags: views, 7, users

Suppose I have a Role A and Role B. 
As per my requirement The Role A is mandatory for a user and the Role B is a good to have role.
I want to filter out the users in the views. So If a user has only Role A, he should be listed. If the user has both the roles he too should be listed but if the user has Role B only he should be restricted.
Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put condition in View's criteria.

1. Go to your view and step ahead to filter.
2. Put first filter as. For example you have role as category A and category B.

Add following filters which can be helpful as per your scenario.

```
   Select content:role (condition : is one of A and B)
                    OR  
   Select content:role (condition : is one of A)
                    AND  
   Select content:role (condition : is none of B)
```

3. Don't forget to add OR and AND condition in between filter fileds.

Hope this will be helpful.